# Statement ignored 14/13 PLS-00222: no function with name 'P' exists in this scope

Tags: plsql, package

Package Specification:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE dt_pkg AS
    PROCEDURE Simpleint(
        p number, n number, r number := 10);

    PROCEDURE Compoundint(
        p number, n number, r number);
END dt_pkg;
/
```

Package BODY:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY dt_pkg  IS
    PROCEDURE Simpleint (p NUMBER, n number, r NUMBER) IS
        si number :=0;
    BEGIN
        si:=p*n*r;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sIMPLE INT: '||si);
    END Simpleint;

   PROCEDURE Compoundint (p number,n number,r number) IS 
       ci number:=0;
   BEGIN
       ci:=p(1+r/100)**n;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COMPOUND INTEREST: '||ci);
    END Compoundint;
END dt_pkg;
/
```

Error I get

> LINE/COL ERROR
>
> ---
>
> 14/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   14/13    PLS-00222: no function with name 'P' exists in this scope

please help 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your package have typo.

```
ci:=p(1+r/100)**n;
```

Try this:

```
ci:=p*(1+r/100)*n;
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks it helped :)